# unexpected agrep() results related to max.distance in R

Tags: r, agrep

**EDIT:** This bug was found in 32-bit versions of R was fixed in R version 2.9.2.

---

This was tweeted to me by @leoniedu today and I don't have an answer for him so I thought I would post it here.

I have read the documentation for agrep() (fuzzy string matching) and it appears that I don't fully understand the max.distance parameter. Here's an example:

```
pattern <- "Staatssekretar im Bundeskanzleramt"
x <- "Bundeskanzleramt"
agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=18) 
agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=19)
```

That behaves exactly like I would expect. There are 18 characters different between the strings so I would expect that to be the threshold of a match. Here's what's confusing me:

```
agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=30) 
agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=31)
agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=32) 
agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=33)
```

Why are 30 and 33 matches, but not 31 and 32? To save you some counting,

```
> nchar("Staatssekretar im Bundeskanzleramt")
[1] 34
> nchar("Bundeskanzleramt")
[1] 16
```

Comment: http://www.nabble.com/possible-agrep-bug--R-2.9.1,-Mac-OS-X-10.5-(PR-13789)-td24285192.html

Comment: Follow up. It was a bug in 32 bit R, which was fixed in R2.9.2. (as detailed in Brian Ripley's message from August 14th at R-list in the link above.)

Comment: if you could post that comment as an answer I'll happily accept it and close this question out with an answer. Thanks for pointing out the bug fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on the R list a while back and reported as a bug in R-bugs-list. I had no useful responses, so I twitted to see if the bug was reproducible or I was just missing something. JD Long was able to reproduce it and kindly posted the question here.

Note that, at least in R, then, agrep is a misnomer since it does *not* matches regular expressions, while grep stands for "Globally search for the Regular Expression and Print". It shouldn't have a problem with patterns longer than the target vector. (i think!)

In my linux server, all is well  but not so in my Mac and Windows machines.

Mac:
sessionInfo()
R version 2.9.1 (2009-06-26) 
i386-apple-darwin8.11.1 
locale:
en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=30) 
[1] 1

> agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=31)
>   integer(0)
>   agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=32) 
>   integer(0)
>   agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=33)
>   [1] 1

Linux:
R version 2.9.1 (2009-06-26) 
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

locale:
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

> agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=30) 
>   [1] 1
>   agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=31)
>   [1] 1
>   agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=32) 
>   [1] 1
>   agrep(pattern,x,max.distance=33)
>   [1] 1

Comment: I think it is safe to say this is a bug. Even if the use case is atypical, I can't see a good reason why this should produce different results on different platforms. Were you able to reproduce this with different strings of different lengths?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your example makes sense.  For the basic grep(), pattern is often a simple or a regular expression, and x is a vector whose element get matched to pattern.  Having pattern as longer string that x strikes me as odd.

Consider this where we just use grep instead of substr:

```
R> grep("vo", c("foo","bar","baz"))   # vo is not in the vector
integer(0)
R> agrep("vo", c("foo","bar","baz"), value=TRUE) # but is close enough to foo
[1] "foo"
R> agrep("vo", c("foo","bar","baz"), value=TRUE, max.dist=0.25) # still foo
[1] "foo"
R> agrep("vo", c("foo","bar","baz"), value=TRUE, max.dist=0.75) # now all match
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
R>
```

Comment: From the docs of agrep, it's a Levenshtein distance, so the length of the pattern doesn't matter -- we're interested in some transformation of the pattern that results in a substring of the string in question.  (It's more interesting when the max distance is held low.)  But it's obviously a bug, since the edit distance doesn't just become discontinuous between 30 and 33.